# Run a PHP script directly in PhpStorm

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, pycharm

1. How can I instantly run the current PHP file in PhpStorm?
2. How can I execute PHP command in PHPstorm like PyCharm?

Comment: that's a bit subjective as your currently edited php file might be part of a long chain of includes & requires that started at an index.php file located at the root and makes no executional sense without going through all that chain..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click in the editor, choose **Run** (or press ctrl+shift+f10) for command line script execution. If you want to test it on a web server, use **Open in Browser** from the same menu (you must have browser and server with mappings properly configured for this).

Comment: @ CrazyCoder  Thank a lot, How can I write command directly on php command line?

Comment: I mean:
php.exe -R <code>
http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: There is no such feature in PhpStorm yet.

Comment: There is a way in version 2016.3 through Interpreter options

Comment: Currently (2023) this does not work if the current open file does not belong to the project, fortunately PHPStorm helpfully informs you of this (haha no it doesn't fu)

Answer (score 7):

On top of @CrazyCoder's solution, in version 2016.3 I came across this issue where I just saw 2 icons like this,

[image: Run dialog]

You should hit the 2nd one!

IF you hit the 2nd (like me) next thing I know, it opened in a browser tab. It is a configuration to open in an embeded web server.

So I wanted to delete this configuration and start a new one. So, I found the entry to through this drop down in the top right corner,

[image: Edit Configuration Dialog]

While picking Edit Configuration, I could change the test configuration.

Hope that helps someone like me, although clearly not the initial poster.

Cheers