# Setting up phpstorm 4 with XAMPP on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, xampp, phpstorm

I need help setting up phpstorm (4.0) with XAMPP which is at the default location c:\xampp\htdocs. I create all my projects at c:\xampp\htdocs\projectname.

Here are the things I have already done:

- Setup the PHP interpretator by going to settings and then PHP (main menu)

[image]

- Go to PHP > Servers and then

[image]

- To setup run configuration I have the done the following:

[image]

Now when I run using the above configuration it just takes me to localhost in my browser, instead of the file I am editing (http://localhost instead of localhost/myproject/myfile.php).

What am I missing? I read the help topics of phpstorm and googled a lot but still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out you don't need to set up run configuration. The answer lies in setting up the mapping in the deployment tab in settings.

(assuming that you are creating your projects in c:\xampp\htdocs)

To do that go to settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) and then choose deployment:
[image]

Under mappings tab, it should look like this:
[image]

And after that you can view the file in the browser through this menu:

[image]

Comment: Very Nice Thankyou.
I just Installed it today, and your Pic tutorial Helped me alot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7739076/104891). If you need to debug, the recommended way to do it [is zero configuration debugging](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/02/zero-configuration-debugging-with-xdebug-and-phpstorm-2-0/).

Comment: The link you mentioned is for running PHP in commandline. I have already created a run configuration as PHP Web Application. And when I launch using that configuration it just shows up as `localhost` in my webbrowser, it DOES NOT include the file that I am editing. What I want it to open is `localhost/myproject/myfile.php`. Please check my 3rd screen shot for the run configuration I have setup.

Comment: You don't need run configuration, the answer to the linked question says to use **Open in Browser** context menu.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have now correctly mapped through the deployment tab in settings to enable view in browser.